# Is there any Debian 11 ISO (~700MB) for offline installation?

Tags: debian, debian-installer

In previous versions of Debian, there used to be a version of ISO designed for offline installation. Here is an example for [Debian 10](https://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/10.12.0/amd64/iso-cd/):

```
debian-10.12.0-amd64-xfce-CD-1.iso
```

However for the latest version, even though that the [download page](https://www.debian.org/CD/http-ftp/) states:

> ### Official CD/DVD images of the stable release
>
> To install Debian on a machine without an Internet connection, it's possible to use CD images (700 MB each) or DVD images (4.7 GB each).

While looking at the [available options](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/), the CD image is nowhere to be found. However the DVD is [there](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-dvd/) as expected.

So the CD won't be provided as usual anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the explanations in the CD download pages are outdated. Offline installation images were produced as long as a consistent installation set for a given desktop environment could fit on a single CD: in [Debian 8](https://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/8.11.1/amd64/iso-cd/), that covered GNOME (the default environment), KDE, LXDE and Xfce; in [Debian 9](https://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/9.13.0/amd64/iso-cd/), the GNOME, KDE, and LXDE installation sets became too large, so they were dropped, leaving only Xfce, which was preserved for [Debian 10](https://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/10.12.0/amd64/iso-cd/).

The Xfce image grew too large for single CDs, so it was dropped for Debian 11, leaving only [the network installation images](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/) in various flavours. [The jigdo templates](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/jigdo-cd/) won’t help — there simply is no offline installation CD image.

For offline installation using optical media, you need [a DVD image](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-dvd/) or [a Blu-ray image](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-bd/). These can also be written to USB sticks. The complete installation set requires 19 single-layer DVDs and is only available [using jigdo](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/jigdo-dvd/).